# How do I add Python to WAMP or just Windows XP to make an Openlayers Build Profile?

Tags: python, windows-xp, openlayers

I would like to use Python to run a profile building script for Openlayers.js. [Here is the documentation page for the Openlayers profile builder.](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Profiles) I wouldn't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with installing Python. It can be downloaded [here](http://www.python.org/download/)

Then add location of your Python installation directory to PATH variable in Environment Variable so that python keyword can be globally accessed in command prompt.

After that you should be able to follow instructions from OpenLayers tutorial that you specified in your question.